# why doesn't iozone generate output file?

Tags: filesystems, performance, io, testing

I'm using `iozone3` for tesing, on Xamin [(an Debian-based OS)](http://xamin.ir/en/). When I enter `iozone` command, for example `iozone -Rab output.xls`, [the test runs successfully](http://s5.picofile.com/file/8135681892/Selection_030.png).

But after running the test (after displaying this message: `iozone test complete.`). Instead of generating the excel file, `iozone` returns the results [in shell](http://s5.picofile.com/file/8135676768/Selection_029.png).

Why doesn't it generate an excel file?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`iozone -Rab output.wks` will do both.  The command will output the flat ascii formatted results for possible import by Excel ( space and tab delimited ) as well as generating the `output.wks` file, which is already in BIFF (Binary Interchange File Format).

The `output.wks` file can be opened directly with Excel, and permits one to skip
importing the flat ascii from standard out.

Comment: As I explained, it doesn't generate "any output file"! either `.xls` or `.wks`!

Comment: Now, it works. I don't know how, but it generates `.wks` output. Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

I tried with separating the flags like below and it worked for me,

```
iozone -R -a -b output.wks
```